# Can a headphone or earbud (bluetooth or wired) transmit malware between computers?

Tags: malware, virus, hardware

I have an old computer and I am sure it has trojan or malicious code but after that I bought new one.
The problem is I did not change my old headphone that I used in my old computer and I plugged it in to the new computer.
So are there any problem to use my old headphone?

Comment: While possible, and completed by researchers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)#Limitations) highly unlikely for normal everyday people.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to airgap a smartphone?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51706/how-to-airgap-a-smartphone)

Comment: What kind of connector do the headphones have?

Comment: dark_st3alth what i mean does my headphone can store malware an transmitted to another computer ?

Comment: multithr3at3d  it is wired connector